# When autocomplete is params returns nil

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Doing autocomplete. In controller `format.json` returns an array of names. from `json` I take the values for autocomplete. But when I start to enter in the input, then in the logs I have:

```
Started GET "/search.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-30 09:41:28 +0300
Processing by PagesController#search as JSON
   (3.1ms)  SELECT "items"."name" FROM "items" WHERE (name LIKE '%%')
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 19.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
```

The problem is that `params[:q]` (in controller) is coming up `nil`.

In **controller**:

```
def search    
  @words = Item.where("name LIKE '%#{params[:q]}%'")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @words.pluck(:name) }
  end
end
```

**JS**:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="q"]').autoComplete({
        minChars: 1,
        source: function(term, response){
            $.getJSON('/search.json', function (data) {
                term = term.toLowerCase();
                var matches = [];
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    if (~data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) matches.push(data[i]);
                response(matches.slice(0,5));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**`.erb`**

```
<input id="hero-demo" autofocus type="text" name="q" style="width:100%;max-width:600px;outline:0">
```

use a plugin [autocomplete](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html)

P.S. On the client autocomplete is working fine.

Comment: You are not passing term with search. That's why its blank.

Comment: give a condition of if data.length > 0 before for loop

Comment: @Pardeep Dhingra, sorry, i'm not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass term as query param:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="q"]').autoComplete({
        minChars: 1,
        source: function(term, response) {
            term = term.toLowerCase();
            $.getJSON('/search.json?q='+ term, function (data) {
                var matches = [];
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    if (~data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) matches.push(data[i]);
                response(matches.slice(0,5));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: url `http://localhost:3000/search.json?q=fahe` returns empty array. But I have values Faheyburgh. Ask for help

Comment: use `ilike` in rails. `@words = Item.where("name ILIKE '%#{params[:q]}%'")`

Comment: Thanks! I first thought that the blame js